# how to get .apk file byte array from its packagename in AS3/AIR?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, installed-applications, package-name

I want to know if it's possible to access a `.apk` file from an installed application on a device (android), via its **package Name** in as3/air?

Right now I have an ANE file which helps me to get packageName (ex: **com.somesite.someApp** or air.myApp), I want to copy the `.apk` file (its **byteArray**), is this possible in as3/air or is there any available ANE file to do this?

Comment: I think you need to create your own ANE to do this.

Comment: well, in that case, do you know any straightforward tutorial about how to create ANE? for android and ios. but, i`m still searching for a less time consuming answer!

Comment: If you know to code in java (for android) then you first should check if it possible to do what you want and if you are able to do this in native... If so, then you can search how to create ANE. It is actually not a big deal. You should create an interface and comunicate through that . You can find on google nice tutorials on how to build native extension for air. good luck!